# Is there a simple formula for $\binom{2n}{n} \pmod{n^3}$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Is there a simple formula for the following? $$f(n) = \binom{2n}{n} \pmod{n^3}$$

I know $f(n) = 2$ iff $n$ is prime and greater than $3$, but I don't know anything about composite numbers.

Comment: $f(n)=2$ iff $n$ is prime?  Not true for $n=2$ or $3$.

Comment: Apologies, should be primes greater than 3.

Comment: Might help to look for papers that generalize Lucas's theorem.

Comment: I first observed this by using Lucas's theorem (though I didn't know it by name) if we take the squares of row n of binomial triangle and sum them this gives $\binom{2n}{n}$ Then by Lucas theorem if we take away 2 it must be divisible by $n^2$ For reasons I dont know this can be increased to $n^3$ for primes greater than 3.

Comment: For $p$ prime, $p>3$, ${2p \choose p} \equiv 2  \bmod p^3$ is just a reformulation of Wolstenholme Theorem.

Comment: We have $(f(n))_{n=1}^\infty=(0,6,20,6,2,60,2,70,506,184,2,1564,\dots)$ and this sequence is not in
the [Online encyclopedia of integer sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=20%2C6%2C2%2C60%2C2%2C70%2C506&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Look at https://neizod.dev/2020/06/30/pascal-triangle-mod-3.html, the binomial triangle mod 3 exhibits a fractal, so computing a coefficient mod 3 can be done efficiently by induction. They give an efficient computation of the binomial coefficients mod 3, you can probably get an efficient recursive formula from it.

Comment: [This](https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1090&context=honorstheses) might be helpful. It looks at Pascal's triangle mod $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment.

Numbers appear to be in this form:

\begin{aligned}
&{2 n \choose n} \mod n^3 \equiv {2 k \choose k} 
+ \frac{t n^3}{k^3} \\\\ & \text{for }kp \quad p \in \mathbb{P} \text{ prime}, 1\geq t > k^3, k \in \mathbb{N}, k > 1
\end{aligned}

For $k=1, {2p \choose p} \equiv 2  \bmod p^3$

which, as stated in the comments, is  a reformulation of Wolstenholme Theorem.